# WebStorm can't find .js or .d.ts file but I can find them in terminal

Tags: webstorm

[image: screenshot]

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         2022/2/19     12:42           1092 crowller.ts
-a----         2022/2/19     13:37           5522 index.js
-a----         2022/2/19     13:32           1839 index.ts
-a----         2022/2/19     21:51           1312 quotes.ts
-a----         2022/2/19     22:09            171 type.d.ts
-a----         2022/2/19     22:09            501 type.js
-a----         2022/2/19     22:08            321 type.ts
```

So they cannot be edited directly in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

If these files are generated from the `.ts` files, they might be explicitly excluded from indexing. Make sure that you have **Tree Appearance > Show Excluded Files** enabled in **Project** view settings:

[image]

and that the **Project** tool window scope is set to **Project** (and not **Project Files**, etc.)